# Taking different records from groups using group by in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have dataframe like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,1]})
>>> df
   id  value
0   1      1
1   1      2
2   1      3
3   2      1
4   2      2
5   2      3
6   2      4
7   3      1
8   4      1
```

Now I want top all records from each group using group id except last 3. That means I want to drop last 3 records from all groups. How can I do it using pandas group_by. This is dummy data.

Comment: kindly post expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter from back by `ascending=False` and then compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater values like `2`, because python count from `0`:

```
df = df[df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=False).gt(2)]
print (df)
   id  value
3   2      1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('id').cumcount(ascending=False))
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    3
4    2
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```